# Как сделать "модульный" класс?

Tags: c++

Появилось желание сделать модульный (в моём понимании) класс, у которого "модули" будут разбросаны по разным файлам, по типу:

```cpp
#include <foo/foo.h>     // для foo()
#include <foo/bar.h>     // для bar()
#include <foo/biz/baz.h> // для biz::baz()
 
int main()
{
    foo::foo();
    foo::bar();
    foo::biz::baz();
}
```

Возможно ли такое сделать? Если да, то я был бы рад увидеть ссылку на статью, где описывается подобный класс, ну или реализацию подобного класса в этой теме :)

А если невозможно, то как работает схема boost::lib::func() в boost?

Comment: `boost::lib` - это пространство имен. что такое должно быть `foo` `biz` `baz` в приведенном примере - хз

Comment: @user7860670 отлично, осталось понять, как это работает, и как это разбить по разным файлам и папкам

Comment: та просто пишете `namespace foo { void foo() {...} }` в одном файле, `namespace foo { void bar(){...} }` в другом.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл это я понимаю, но как можно разбить по разным папкам, как в boost?

Comment: кладете один файл в одну папку, другой - в другую...

Comment: @user7860670 я не понимаю, как их соединить namespace-ом

Comment: Что значит соединить? В одном файле написали `namespace foo {void foo();}`, в другом написали `namespace foo {void bar();}`. Подключите первый файл, сможете писать `foo:foo();`, подключите второй - сможете писать `foo::bar();`, подключите оба - сможете писать и так и так.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл спасибо!